# reference to connect is ambiguous QQuickItem QMainWindow

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qcustomplot

I am trying to use [QCustomPlot](http://www.qcustomplot.com/)'s example of the following folder, in my program:

`/examples/plots`

and at the same time **I want it accessible from QML**. So, I added <**QQuickItem**> and it resulted in the error stated in the title.

The code:

```
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>
#include "../../qcustomplot.h" 

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow :  public QQuickItem, public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
```

**What should I do to make it accessible from QML and solve the error too?**

Comment: Can you add some information what QMainWindow is? if it is a subclass  of QWidget I think that you need to find some articles about embedding QQuickView into QtWidgets application or vice versa.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QMainWindow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Qt Widgets applications and there are Qt Quick applications. Choose one.

`QCustomPlot` lets you create widgets for a Qt Widgets application.

You can not embed a QWidget in a Qt Quick (=QML) application. The only thing you can do to some extend is to embed QML in your Qt Widgets application. In this case your `MainWindow` inherits `QMainWindow` only and contains a `QQuickView` (see http://www.ics.com/blog/combining-qt-widgets-and-qml-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer).